# jquery how to get data from this array

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

This is my c# code:

```
Dictionary<string, double[][]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double[][]>();
dictionary.Add("ServiceLevel", finalArray);
dictionary.Add("NumberOfCalls", numberOfCallsArray);
```

Where `finalArray` and `numberOfCallsArray` is `double[][]` full of data.

I send it to jquery like this:

```
string jsonformatstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsonformatstring);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Then in jquery after doing a json request and get the data successfully. I do this:

```
var data = $.map(result, function (arr, key) {
               return { label: key, data: arr };
           });

console.log(data["ServiceLevel"] + "--");
```

#### My problem

I got `undefined` in the console when I tried this: `console.log(data["ServiceLevel"] + "--");`

Maybe I am getting the value in the wrong way?

#### Update 1

I did this:
    console.log(result);
and I got this

[image]

#### Update 2

I tried this:

```
var s = JSON.stringify(result); console.log(s)
```

The result is this:

```
{"ServiceLevel":[[1390608000000,50],[1392595200000,0],[1393286400000,66.66666666666667],[1393891200000,50],[1394064000000,0],[1394236800000,50],[1394323200000,0],[1394841600000,50],[1394928000000,33.333333],[1395014400000,0],[1395100800000,50],[1395273600000,0],[1395446400000,0],[1395619200000,0],[1395705600000,0],[1395878400000,50],[1396310400000,50],[1396483200000,0],[1396656000000,0],[1396828800000,50],[1396915200000,50],[1397001600000,50],[1397347200000,33.333333],[1397433600000,50],[1397952000000,0],[1398124800000,50],[1398556800000,0],[1398902400000,45],[1399075200000,0],[1399161600000,0],[1399334400000,0],[1399420800000,50],[1399680000000,0],[1399852800000,50],[1399939200000,0],[1400025600000,0],[1400112000000,33.333333],[1400284800000,40],[1400371200000,0],[1400457600000,50],[1400716800000,40],[1402185600000,50],[1402358400000,50],[1402531200000,0],[1402704000000,44.117647],[1402876800000,50],[1403308800000,50],[1403481600000,50],[1403913600000,0],[1407283200000,0],[1390780800000,100],[1391040000000,100],[1391558400000,100],[1392249600000,100],[1392681600000,75],[1392854400000,100],[1396137600000,100],[1397260800000,100],[1399507200000,100],[1400889600000,88.888888],[1401840000000,100],[1403654400000,100],[1407369600000,70.83333300000001],[1407628800000,100],[1408060800000,100],[1408233600000,50],[1408320000000,0]],"NumberOfCalls":[[1390608000000,50],[1392595200000,2],[1393286400000,14],[1393891200000,7],[1394064000000,1],[1394236800000,36],[1394323200000,3],[1394841600000,10],[1394928000000,11],[1395014400000,2],[1395100800000,45],[1395273600000,24],[1395446400000,13],[1395619200000,11],[1395705600000,11],[1395878400000,3],[1396310400000,18],[1396483200000,44],[1396656000000,2],[1396828800000,4],[1396915200000,25],[1397001600000,3],[1397347200000,11],[1397433600000,10],[1397952000000,15],[1398124800000,18],[1398556800000,1],[1398902400000,13],[1399075200000,2],[1399161600000,2],[1399334400000,1],[1399420800000,16],[1399680000000,3],[1399852800000,19],[1399939200000,32],[1400025600000,1],[1400112000000,20],[1400284800000,6],[1400371200000,3],[1400457600000,9],[1400716800000,12],[1402185600000,21],[1402358400000,14],[1402531200000,4],[1402704000000,37],[1402876800000,13],[1403308800000,18],[1403481600000,2],[1403913600000,1],[1407283200000,2],[1390780800000,2],[1391040000000,6],[1391558400000,6],[1392249600000,5],[1392681600000,6],[1392854400000,1],[1396137600000,2],[1397260800000,2],[1399507200000,1],[1400889600000,18],[1401840000000,6],[1403654400000,3],[1407369600000,16]
```

Comment: can you please post JSON object you got, that make more easy to answer

Comment: @Aaron do you mean `console.log(result)` ?

Comment: yes...do JSON.stringify(result), that will give json string of response object

Comment: @Aaron oh sorry, I edited the question before I saw your new comment. so did you mean `var s = JSON.stringify(result); console.log(s)` ?

Comment: yes, that what i wish :p

Comment: @Aaron I updated again

Comment: please edit your previous comments,don't make chat long here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is not clear, so i am assuming you got data something like

```
var result = {"ServiceLevel":[[1390608000000,50],[1392595200000,0]], 
              "NumberOfCalls":[[12,10],[100,0]]};
```

var arr = $.map(result, function (arr, key) {
  return { label: key, data: arr };           });

Converting to Array:

```
var arr = $.map(result, function (arr, key) {
               return { label: key, data: arr };
           });
```

Reading Elements:

```
element at position 1:
 arr[0].data[0][1] is 1

 element at position 3:
 arr[0].data[2][2] is 3
```

to get key use:

```
arr[0].label , it will give you "ServiceLevel"
arr[1].label , it will give you "NumberOfCalls"
```

Comment: the input is clear now I edit the question please check

Comment: it is same as used for example, you can find your object at 0 index of array...further multi-dimesional array can be find with key data. Note:label has no use, your data is always at 0 index object, as map function return single object

Comment: so let me explain what I want. in  query I want to have  a label `ServiceLevel` and its corresponding array **and** a label `NumberOfCalls` and its corresponding array. what wrong did I do and how to fix that? plus, I don't see the `NumberOfCalls` I don't know why:( help please

Comment: I though that using the dictionary in c# will send both values, but it seems just the first one, which is `ServiceLevel` has been send

Comment: please did you get what I want? or I explain more?

Comment: so can I say arr[0] is the **first** `double[][]` and arr[1] is the **second** `double[][]` ?

Comment: yes...exactly to get key name, use arr[0].label and to get corresponding array use arr[0].data

Comment: when I tried `console arr[0].data` I got `1390608000000,50,1392595200000,0,1393286400000,6....... etc` without `[` and `]` but I need to have array of array. what should I do please?

Comment: I will accept your answer but I will ask another answer,

Comment: i think you are looking in Internet explorer, console.log is used to show strings so don't worry you are safe to use your array. just check: a[0].data contain array of array....a[0].data[0] contain first array, arr[0].data[0][0] contain first element of first array...and so on...arr[0].data[1][1] contain second element of second array :)

Comment: now I solve it and I draw the chart but I got another problelem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362640/flot-why-the-line-goes-back-to-the-top-left

Comment: could you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366372/barwidth-option-is-not-working-on-jquery-flot

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $.map(result, function (arr, key) {
               return { label: key, data: arr };
           });
```

You're returning an associative array with "label" and "data" elements. data["data"] should contain what you're looking for.

If you did:

```
       $.map(result, function (arr, key) {
           console.log(arr["ServiceLevel"] + "--"); 
           return { label: key, data: arr };
       });
```

you'd see it being returned. it's just because you've wrapped your "data" in another array.

Comment: did you mean to comment the `return` statement in the `map` function?

Comment: so you mean to delete that map function at all? then do this `var data = result` ?

Comment: No, what I meant was the "var data" is set to an associative array containing "label" and "data". if you do data["data"] you'll get the real data

Comment: I already told you in the question that I tried `data["ServiceLevel"]` and I got `undifined`

Comment: Yes, because you're returning an array that has only "label" and "data" in it. "ServiceLevel" does not exist within the returned array, but it may within the inner array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting undefined because you didn't parse the json you received from your c# code.
I had this problem too, the thing is this :

```
string jsonformatstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsonformatstring);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

returns a String. To be used as Json you need to parse it, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` only format the object into {[ key:value ]}.

here's a sample of an ajax success function i made with json :

```
success: function (data) {//on success
    var results = JSON.parse(data);         //parse result to work on it

    $.each(results, function (index, element) {
        //do something
    });
```

I don't know how you retrieve your Json string but try parsing it before working on it :)

Comment: please check my update question, it seems that just the `ServiceLevel` exist, not the `NumberOfCalls` why?