# flot why the line goes back to the top left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

This is my code:

```
var holder = $('#line-chart');

           if (holder.length) {
               $.plot(holder, [
                    { data: data[0].data, lines: { show: true }, label:"Service Level" },
                    { data: data[1].data, bars: { show: true }, yaxis: 2, label:"# Of Calls" } // set second series to use second axis
               ], {
                   yaxes: [{
                       min: 0, // options for first axis
                       tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
                           return val + '%';
                       }
                   }, {
                       alignTicksWithAxis: 1, // options for second axis, put it on right
                       position: "right"
                   }],
                   xaxis: {
                       min: minVal.getTime(),
                       max: maxVal.getTime(),
                       mode: "time",
                       timeformat: timeFormat,
                       //twelveHourClock: true,
                       tickSize: [tickVal, modeChart],
                       //monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                       tickLength: 0
                   },
                   grid: {
                       hoverable: true,
                       clickable: false,
                       borderWidth: 0
                   },
               });
           }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Please notice that the `Service Level` line (the orange one) is goes from `Aug` to the top left. could you help me here please?

I got the data from this operation

```
 var data = $.map(result, function (arr, key) {
               return { label: key, data: arr };
           });
```

where `results` comes from json request, and to print you the `result` I did this

```
var s = JSON.stringify(result);
           console.log(s)
```

and this is what the console shows

> {"ServiceLevel":[[1390608000000,50],[1392595200000,0],[1393286400000,66.66666666666667],[1393891200000,50],[1394064000000,0],[1394236800000,50],[1394323200000,0],[1394841600000,50],[1394928000000,33.333333],[1395014400000,0],[1395100800000,50],[1395273600000,0],[1395446400000,0],[1395619200000,0],[1395705600000,0],[1395878400000,50],[1396310400000,50],[1396483200000,0],[1396656000000,0],[1396828800000,50],[1396915200000,50],[1397001600000,50],[1397347200000,33.333333],[1397433600000,50],[1397952000000,0],[1398124800000,50],[1398556800000,0],[1398902400000,45],[1399075200000,0],[1399161600000,0],[1399334400000,0],[1399420800000,50],[1399680000000,0],[1399852800000,50],[1399939200000,0],[1400025600000,0],[1400112000000,33.333333],[1400284800000,40],[1400371200000,0],[1400457600000,50],[1400716800000,40],[1402185600000,50],[1402358400000,50],[1402531200000,0],[1402704000000,44.117647],[1402876800000,50],[1403308800000,50],[1403481600000,50],[1403913600000,0],[1407283200000,0],[1390780800000,100],[1391040000000,100],[1391558400000,100],[1392249600000,100],[1392681600000,75],[1392854400000,100],[1396137600000,100],[1397260800000,100],[1399507200000,100],[1400889600000,88.888888],[1401840000000,100],[1403654400000,100],[1407369600000,70.83333300000001],[1407628800000,100]],"NumberOfCalls":[[1390608000000,50],[1392595200000,2],[1393286400000,14],[1393891200000,7],[1394064000000,1],[1394236800000,36],[1394323200000,3],[1394841600000,10],[1394928000000,11],[1395014400000,2],[1395100800000,45],[1395273600000,24],[1395446400000,13],[1395619200000,11],[1395705600000,11],[1395878400000,3],[1396310400000,18],[1396483200000,44],[1396656000000,2],[1396828800000,4],[1396915200000,25],[1397001600000,3],[1397347200000,11],[1397433600000,10],[1397952000000,15],[1398124800000,18],[1398556800000,1],[1398902400000,13],[1399075200000,2],[1399161600000,2],[1399334400000,1],[1399420800000,16],[1399680000000,3],[1399852800000,19],[1399939200000,32],[1400025600000,1],[1400112000000,20],[1400284800000,6],[1400371200000,3],[1400457600000,9],[1400716800000,12],[1402185600000,21],[1402358400000,14],[1402531200000,4],[1402704000000,37],[1402876800000,13],[1403308800000,18],[1403481600000,2],[1403913600000,1],[1407283200000,2],[1390780800000,2],[1391040000000,6],[1391558400000,6],[1392249600000,5],[1392681600000,6],[1392854400000,1],[1396137600000,2],[1397260800000,2],[1399507200000,1],[1400889600000,18],[1401840000000,6],[1403654400000,3],[1407369600000,16],[1407628800000,1]]}

Comment: it's too hard to find, please use less data to find the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line goes back to top-left because that is what your data does.

Your first service level is [1390608000000,50].  Subsequent service levels have the first number (the x coordinate) increasing .... Until it comes to :

```
[1407283200000,0],[1390780800000,100],[1391040000000,100], ....
```

See - the x coordinate has switched back to (pretty much) the same as the start, but the y coordinate is 100%.

So no problem with your code - it's the data.

Comment: could you help me in this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364240/flot-jquery-y-axis-option-is-not-working

Comment: Looks like others are quick to help - Good luck :)

Comment: could you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365103/flot-dynamic-bar-width

Comment: could you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366372/barwidth-option-is-not-working-on-jquery-flot