# flot jquery y axis option is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

This is my yasix option

```
yaxes: {
                   min: 0,
                   max: 100,
                   tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
                       return val + '%';
                   }
               },
```

but when I run the chart, the max is not 100, plus there is no `%` sign.

what wrong did i do pleaes?

I didn't post other code becuase I think the problem from the code above, if you see that my code is correct and you need more code kindly tell me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a single value, the option is `yaxis` instead of `yaxes`. If you have multiple values, you should provide an array.

Comment: I see, I was using it when there were 2 y axis, I will try and update u

Comment: could you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366372/barwidth-option-is-not-working-on-jquery-flot

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, see `yaxes` instead of `yaxis` . And check if val is in Number or String.. print and see if it is showing as `object`

Comment: what do you mean by `And check if val is in Number or String.. print and see if it is showing as object` , I have integer numbers from 0 to 100

Comment: if you append a string with object types it wont return you a string. happy tat it worked with the `yaxis` spell correction