# flot dynamic bar width

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

This is the code i used to use for bars

```
bars: {
                   show: true,
                   barWidth: 12 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 300,
```

that width works with me when the `min` and `max` value of x axis is `2014-2-2.gettime()` and `2014-9-9` respectively (i am trying to give you the idea not the exact syntax).

but the bar seems to wide when the data is from june to july

is there a way to make flot itself make the width and make it not too large and not too small ?

Comment: If you simply remove the barWdith setting, it will default to evenly distribute across the width of the container.

Comment: @briansol did you mean that the width will be calculated automaticall or the width will be in the minimue value?

Comment: @briansol when I removed the `barWidht` the bars didn't even shown

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, `flot` won't auto-scale the bars.  The default `barWidth: 1, // in units of the x axis`, of course, isn't going to cut it for large-scale time plots.  So here's my attempt for a simple algorithm which leaves equal sized bars and white space in between bars:

```
calcBarWidth = function(numBars, minTime, maxTime){
   // assuming an even distribution
   var totWidth = maxTime - minTime;
   // totalWidth = (numBars * barSize) + ((1 + numBars) * barSize), solved for barSize
   return (totWidth / ((2 * numBars) + 1));
}
```

Untested code...