# barwidth option is not working on jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to draw a line chart with bar chart. everything went well.
This is my code

```
 $.plot(holder, [
                    { data: data[0].data, lines: { show: true }, label:"Service Level" },
                    { data: data[1].data, bars: { show: true }, yaxis: 2, label:"# Of Calls" } // set second series to use second axis
               ], {
                   yaxes: [{
                       min: 0, // options for first axis,
                       max: 100,
                       tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
                           return val + '%';
                       }
                   }, {
                       alignTicksWithAxis: 1, // options for second axis, put it on right
                       position: "right"
                   }],
                   xaxis: {
                       min: minVal.getTime(),
                       max: maxVal.getTime(),
                       mode: "time",
                       timeformat: timeFormat,
                       //twelveHourClock: true,
                       tickSize: [tickVal, modeChart],
                       //monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                       tickLength: 0
                   },
                   bars: {
                        barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60,
                   },
                   grid: {
                       hoverable: true,
                       clickable: false,
                       borderWidth: 0
                   },
               });
           }
```

I already set the `barWidth` and whatever I change the value, the width of the bar is not changing. could you help me please?

I am talking about the blue one in this image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barWidth` is a [series option](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series), you can specify it globally or per series:

Globally:

```
...
series: { // you are missing this
    bars: {
        barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60,
    },
}
...
```

Per Series:

```
{ data: data[1].data, bars: { show: true, barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60 }, yaxis: 2, label:"# Of Calls" } // set second series to use second axis
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I will test and update you, please is there anyway so I can make the bar width automatically adjuctd according to the data and available width? this bar width is driving me crazy :)

Comment: I tried your second solution, but nothing change, still the bar width is static

Comment: now I tried your first solution but still nothing changed :(

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec, works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/VTOI2efymHh2unB9RGBz?p=preview

Comment: it works with me just on firefox not chrome. i don't know why. +1 i will accept your ansewr, but please if you know why it works just on firefox, kindly tell me . many thanks

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec, works for me in chrome.  Make sure to check your javascript console for errors, if none, I'd suggest building a jsfiddle or plnkr, slowly adding in the options.  Also, note StephenThomas's answer below, he does have a good point.

Comment: yes he has a point, which I discovered later, but he didn't gave the right solution, which is the correct place of `barWidth`

Answer (score 2):

Since your x-axis is time, the units are milliseconds. By specifying a bar width of `24*60*60` you're setting the width to be 1/1000th of a day, or about 1.5 minutes. For a chart that spans several months, 1.5 minutes is tiny and may not be what you want. If you want your bar widths to be a day, then you should specify a bar width of `24*60*60*1000` instead.

Comment: +1 thanks for the efforts, but I gave you an example of several months, actually, i tried it with a one day range and still the same but when `@Mark` gave me an answer, that answer works for me